# Save the URL to the list of gravity form items

Tags: wordpress, gravityforms

I want to create a list in the Gravity plugin
So that when I select any value and press the button, it goes to the separate URL
I mean, every item in the list contains an URL that goes to that URL by pressing a button.

Comment: By "pressing a button" do you mean the submit button?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean

Comment: How many items do you have, if they are not too many, you can achieve that using form confirmations and conditional logic.

Comment: I did the same. But it does not give me value parametr